# Howto get value property by using variable in Kohana Orm

Tags: php, orm, model, kohana

I want to get value from ORM object by setting the property name from variable. Below
is the example on what im thinking.

```
$field_name = 'name';

$value = ORM::factory('table')->GetValueByField($field_name);

echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// $id required, because your model must be loaded
$values = ORM::factory('table', $id)->{$field_name};
```

Its a `__get` magic, [ORM API link](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/ORM#__get)